# AudioInputStream to base64

Tags: java, arrays, base64, audioinputstream

I'm using some code to read some audio files from `HTTP GET` requests and mixing them up. I end up with an `AudioInputStream`. If I write it to a file (`ais` is the `AudioInputStream`) with the code bellow the file is created with success and if I try to read it javascript I can get the `base64` of the file with no problems.

```
AudioSystem.write(
      ais
      ,AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE
      ,new File("test.wav"));
```

But what I need to do is with the `AudioInputStream` extract the byte array (and convert it to `base64` to send it to some other part of the code. I can't save the file to disk, I need to do this from the application memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to do it by writing it to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead and then converting the byte array to `base64`

```
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

AudioSystem.write(
       ais
       ,AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE
       ,baos);

audioInByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
```